# I want to start building an software that can help me to write same text simultaneously in 2 different messenger windows

Tags: c#, windows

I want to start building an application that can help me to write same text simultaneously in 2 different messenger windows.

I just want some ideas, sdk's, if it is possible on Windows 7.

I ve heard about CPN Mouse Project, but that is for XP. Also, now I am downloading Windows Multi-Point Mouse SDK from Microsoft.

Any other ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please define what "messenger" is?

Comment: Messenger clients...like Yahoo!Messenger, Skype, etc.

Comment: This is a terrible question. You haven't listed any solutions you have tried. You give poor detail as to the actual requirements of the project. Are the windows on two different machines or the same client ? Please edit your question if you really want a reasonable response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you simply want a program in which you can type in messages and it will send it to other windows, eg. a messenger app. This can be done using [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx).

You may also want to take a look at [this.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18366/Sending-Keystrokes-to-another-Application-in-C)

Comment: yes...this is what i need...but if you can give me some references to send also the mouse actions on one window...i will give you 50 rep point.Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to find the window size in other to know the place to click with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637819/find-window-height-width/8256122#8256122 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c/2416762#2416762 to simulate the click.

Comment: Also, I'd add that it should be preferable to send the messages using enter key in the window than simulating mouse clicks

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to find the second window with the function 'FindWindowEx'.

In the window you type, you catch the keypres or keydown event and copy all keystrokes to the second window, using the handles. Please google or in stackoverflow on 'keylogger' for examples.